# Google Apps Script internationalization (i18n)

Tags: internationalization, google-apps-script

The docs don't seem to mention anything - is there a recommended way on how to do i18n within Google Apps Scripts? Especially ones published as a WebApp? Is there even a way to find out the user's locale?

Comment: user's locale for setting out see session type for which user is using it?

Comment: @ViralShah : I don't understand - neither the `Session` nor the `User` have a locale setting.

Comment: It's a reasonable feature request to raise on the issue tracker.

Comment: I did: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2040

Comment: And this: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2310 - Please star if you are interested in this as well.

Answer (score 7):

Session.getActiveUserLocale() should return the locale.

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale%28%29)