# Localizing Google Add-ons

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

We have a published Google Docs Add-on. Where we need 5 different languages. We are reading the [Internationalizing Your App](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#overview) documentation. It's mainly describing how it can be done if you are publishing an Chrome Extension (uploading .zip). However an Docs Add-on is written in Google Apps Script.

As per documentation we need to add:

**manifest.json**

**messages.json**

"and providing a _locales directory in your app's ZIP file"

Here is where we get trouble. How can we add folders in Google Apps Script & how can we add .json files? The only options are script-files & html-files.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That documentation is NOT for [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) at all, but for [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). So it does not *directly* apply.

Briefly looking through Google Apps Script docs, i18n is not mentioned. It does not seem like there is any supporting library for it.

Note that according to an [earlier question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151787/google-apps-script-internationalization-i18n) you can get the user's locale with [`Session.getActiveUserLocale())`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuserlocale) and implement your own i18n.

However, that probably won't enable item i18n in the Web Store itself. There's a [bug report describing this situation](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4736).

The bug report mentions that you could potentially throw in the locale fields/folders in the *generated* Chrome app by editing it directly using [this procedure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/domain-wide-web-app#distributing_checklist). That much is not tested though.

Comment: Thanks! It's quite complicated, but it seems to work downloading the CRX file, and adding the values as the Chrome Apps reference. Thanks!

Comment: @enedebe could you provide an example of the process for add languages to a Google add-on? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we did it at [Vocal](https://vocal.email). It's fairly simple and easy to implement (Our example supports english and spanish).

**1. Create a dictionary with keys for the different strings in your app:**

```
const LANGUAGE_MAP = {
  "RECORD_MESSAGE": {
    "en": "Record message",
    "es": "Grabar mensaje"
  },
  "RECORD_MESSAGE_TEXT": {
    "en": "1. Click here to record your voice",
    "es": "1. Haga clic aquí para grabar su voz"
  }
}
```

**2. Create a function that takes a key as input and returns the string in the proper language based on the user's locale**
This is done using `Session.getActiveUserLocale()`

```
function translate(key) {
  locale = Session.getActiveUserLocale();
  if (['en', 'es'].includes(locale)) {
  return LANGUAGE_MAP[key][locale]
  }
  else {
    return LANGUAGE_MAP[key]['en']
  }
}
```

3. Replace all your bare strings with the function created above and the string as key.

```
CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(translate("RECORD_MESSAGE_TEXT"));
```

Comment: `Session.getActiveUserLocale` does not work for me, returns empty string. There are multiple bug reports on google issue tracker too.