# How to internationalize universalActions label in a Google Workspace Add-On

Tags: json, google-apps-script, internationalization, manifest, google-workspace-add-ons

I set up a Gmail addon with an     `universalActions` menu.
The label should be defined by     `Session.getActiveUserLocale()` in any way.

Since variables are not allowed in the manifest file (`appscript.json`) I have no idea how to do it.

I was looking around for solutions but it seems there are none.
e.g.
[Localizing Google Add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478491/localizing-google-add-ons)

[Localizing Google Add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478491/localizing-google-add-ons)

Comment: Instead of saying that you didn't found anything briefly describe your search efforts as what search keywords you used, what are the most relevant questions and answers that you reviewed, etc. as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the type of addon. I was thinking of a different project. 

My search was for localisation, internationalisation, using variables in manifest file, translation, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be a solution I removed the `universalActions` completely from manifest file *appsscript.json*.

To get the menu in different languages I added it on each card.

```
return CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addCardAction(CardService.newCardAction()
      .setText('test').setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('testfunction')))
    .build();
```