# Internationalization in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, internationalization

Internationalization in Google App Script:

I am building a Gmail Addon. I am not finding any way to have internationalization in Gmail Addons. Is this something unsupported by Google ?

What is the best way to go about this?

I see some old libraries, but nothing on a proper way to implement this.

Comment: I think this one is an on-going issue. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151787/google-apps-script-internationalization-i18n). It is quiet bit outdated but the issue tracker keep on moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that guide https://github.com/pffy/googlescript-locale/blob/master/GetActiveUserLocale.gs Create a javascript object and use it with Session language.